# Why does this definition of an attractor work, and where does it come from?

Tags: definition, dynamical-systems, chaos-theory

I recetly saw an attractor of a function being defind as the point $(x,f(x))$ such that
$$|f(f(x))'|<1$$
Where does this definition come from, both litterally, as in where can I read more about it, and why does it work?

Edit:
Here's the paper where the definition was used, page 13:
http://www.csun.edu/~vcmth02i/Collatz.pdf

Comment: An [attractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attractor) point is usually required to be a fixed point.

Comment: It would be great to know the context in which this "definition" arises.

Comment: Done. Added the paper that I saw the definition. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cited paper is talking about an attracting 2-*cycle*, $(c_1, c_2)$, where $c_2=f(c_1)$ and $c_1=f(c_2)$.
Then $c_1$ and $c_2$ are attracting fixed points of $f\circ f$.

The condition on the derivative is $|(f\circ f)'(c_i)|<1$, not $|f(f(c_i))'|<1$, which does not make much sense.

Note that $(f\circ f)'(c_i)=f'(f(c_i))f'(c_i)=f'(c_1)f'(c_2)$.

Comment: So I suppose I understand the definition provided, but what paper/text does it come from?

Comment: @user3210986, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_point.